# Timer inside Android service

Tags: android, timer, android-service

I have an Android service that starts a timer that does stuff:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new VeryImportantTask(), 0, RATE);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

I know Services are singleton but, does `onStartCommand` method called each time that I call `startService()`? If so, I should control that my timer is just started the first time, shouldn't I? I'm thinking in a static boolean flag in the service. Is there a better way?

Comment: I think if you are doing some task at repeated interval you could use AlarmManager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case i.e **START_STICKY** you can simply check the intent value **`nullity`**
like this

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      if(null==intent){
              // service restarted do what you want
        }
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

because first time the intent will not be **null** and it will be **null every time** in case of a restart with `START_STICKY`.