# How to check if the putExtra exist?

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

I have a diagram as follows

```
Activity 1 --send data--> Service1
                            ^
                            |
Open app--------------------
                            ^
                            |
Activity 2------------------
```

It means the activity 1 will send the data to a Service 1. The service 1 is a running background service with return in `onStartCommand()` is `START_STICKY`. Currently, I am using `putExtra()` function to exchange the data. And in the service I will getExtra data as follows steps:

In `Activity 1`

```
Intent start_service = new Intent(getContext(), ConnectService.class);
start_service.putExtra("data", "123");
getContext().startService(start_service);
```

In onStartCommand() of `Service 1`

```
 String data=null;
 if(intent.hasExtra("data")){
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if(!bundle.getString("data").equals(null)){
        data= bundle.getString("data");
    }
  }
  else
       data="0";
```

I used the `hasExtra` function to check whether `data` is set or not. In my purpose, the case 1 is that the Service 1 can receive data from the `Activity 1` . In the case 2, if we do not start from the Activity 1, for example, when I clean all running app, the phone will be open the Service 1 automatically due to `START_STICKY`, the Service 1 will set data equal "0". Hence, my issue is from second case, the application is crash because it cannot check the Extra exist or not.

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.content.Intent.hasExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

How could I fix the issue? Thank all

Comment: try this , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38265993/timer-inside-android-service

Comment: Thank but some case, the service can restart from other Activity , not Activity 1. So your solution cannot solved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 String data=null;
 if(getIntent()!=null && getIntent().getExtras()!=null){
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(!bundle.getString("data").equals(null)){
        data= bundle.getString("data");
    }
 }
 else
 data="0";
```

try this,notice the change in if condition

Comment: I used it before but it also get error `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference` when I start service from other activity

Answer (score 2):

At this step `intent` might be null. Also your code results in a possible null value for data. Instead you could do something like the following:

```
String data = null;
if (intent != null) {
    data = intent.getStringExtra("data");
}
if (data == null) {
    data = "0";
}
```

Also you should not use `equals()` to check for null values. Always use `== null` instead.

Comment: Thanks but it also get error `String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`. Let assume a simple example, the activity 1 is not MAIN and LAUNCHER activity. The activity 2 is main. Both activity 1 and 2 can start Service but only activity 1 can send data.

Comment: I don't see how this is possible. You should replace all your posted code with it. `if (intent != null)` should guard against the exception you get.